# How many ways to delete call history on android?

Tags: android

I know the only way to delete call history is to use ContentResolver, example:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```

Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");

int d  = getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

d returns no. of records deleted.

also check below code

```
int res = Call_logs.this.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,"_ID = "+ calls_id_list.get(i),null);
    if (res == 1) {
        // Log delete

    } else {
        // Log not Delete

    }
```

here calls_id_list is a array of call logs id.

Comment: thanks Dhaval, I wonder is there a way that not using ContentResolver ?